# syntax highlighting in emacs with .Rnw files

Tags: emacs, latex, sweave, ess

When working with .Rnw files, emacs with ess highlights the R-code blocks in purple.  This is great, but the issue I'm having is after the R-code, everything is still purple!

Some people have said that it goes away once you put in more R-code later on, but that didn't work for me.

For example,

```
This is some text
<<>>=
This is some R-code, its in purple
@
This is some more text, but its still in purple!
```

Here is my .emacs file

```
(setq TeX-auto-save t)
(setq TeX-parse-self t)
(setq TeX-PDF-mode t)


(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'flyspell-mode)

(require 'ess-site)
(require 'whitespace)
(setq whitespace-style '(face lines-tail))

(setq backup-by-copying t
      backup-directory-alist '(("." . "~/.emacsBkups"))
      delete-old-versions t
      kept-new-versions 5
      kept-old-versions 2
      version-control t)

;; does not use white-space mode in latex-mode
(define-global-minor-mode white-space-no-latex-mode whitespace-mode
  (lambda ()
    (when (not (memq major-mode
             (list 'latex-mode)))
      (whitespace-mode))))

(white-space-no-latex-mode)
(ess-toggle-underscore nil)

(setq TeX-view-program-list '(("Evince" "evince --page-index=%(outpage) %o")))
(setq TeX-view-program-selection '((output-pdf "Evince")))



;; Make TeX and RefTex aware of Snw and Rnw files
(setq reftex-file-extensions
      '(("Snw" "Rnw" "nw" "tex" ".tex" ".ltx") ("bib" ".bib")))
(setq TeX-file-extensions
      '("Snw" "Rnw" "nw" "tex" "sty" "cls" "ltx" "texi" "texinfo"))

;; Lets you do 'C-c C-c Sweave' from your Rnw file
(defun emacsmate-add-Sweave ()
  (add-to-list 'TeX-command-list
           '("Sweave" "R CMD Sweave %s"
         TeX-run-command nil (latex-mode) :help "Run Sweave") t)
  (add-to-list 'TeX-command-list
           '("LatexSweave" "%l %(mode) %s"
         TeX-run-TeX nil (latex-mode) :help "Run Latex after Sweave") t)
  (setq TeX-command-default "Sweave"))

(add-hook 'Rnw-mode-hook 'emacsmate-add-Sweave)
```

I imagine it is something to do with my .emacs file.  But I don't know enough about lisp to figure out where the conflict is going on...

**EDIT** I found the culprit...the problem only arises when I am using an underscore within the R-code chunk.  I get the error "missing $ inserted" and it points to the "_" in the R-code.  How do I tell emacs that this is R-code, and it should be ignored?

Comment: Sometimes adding a blank line before and after the `<<>>=` and `@` helps for me.  Not sure why.

Comment: Are you using Rnw-mode?

Comment: Yeah I am using Rnw-mode